# Deserialize XML in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a class named CSound

```
public class CSound
{ 
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string file { get; set; }
    public string fav { get; set; }
}
```

..from this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ArrayOfSounds xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CSound>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>SampleName1</name>
    <file>SampleFileName1</file>
    <fav>true</fav>
  </CSound>
  <CSound>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>SampleName2</name>
    <file>SampleFileName2</file>
    <fav>false</fav>
  </CSound>
  <CSound>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>SampleName3</name>
    <file>SampleFileName3</file>
    <fav>true</fav>
  </CSound>
  <CSound>
    <id>4</id>
    <name>SampleName4</name>
    <file>SampleFileName4</file>
    <fav>false</fav>
  </CSound>
  <CSound>
    <id>5</id>
    <name>SampleName5</name>
    <file>SampleFileName5</file>
    <fav>true</fav>
  </CSound>
</ArrayOfSounds>
```

T'm trying to deserialize using this section of code

```
   Assembly assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
   Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SaynarSounds.Resources.XML.Sounds.xml");

   List<CSound> sounds;
   using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
   {
       XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<CSound>));
       sounds = (List<CSound>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
   }

   if (sounds == null)
   {
       sounds = new List<CSound>();
   }

   return sounds;
```

Find the resource and start loading, but in deserialization I get this error:

System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document.

Can you help me?

UPDATE:

the exception throw this message

> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException:
>   There is an error in XML document. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException:  was not
>   expected 02-04 12:29:58.045 E/mono-rt ( 3046):   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadRoot
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping rootMap) [0x0005b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:182
>   02-04 12:29:58.045 E/mono-rt ( 3046):   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadRoot ()
>   [0x00028] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:87
>   02-04 12:29:58.045 E/mono-rt ( 3046):   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader reader) [0x0001c] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs:364

But I don't have an `xmlns=''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that if you attempt to serialize a root object of type `List<CSounds>` you will get XML like the following:

```
<ArrayOfCSound>
  <CSound>
    <id>one</id>
  </CSound>
</ArrayOfCSound>
```

Notice that the root element `<ArrayOfX>` ends in the same string `X` as the nested item elements `<X>`?  This is inconsistent with your sample XML where the root element is named `ArrayOfSound` but the item elements are named `CSound`.

To work around this inconsistency, you will need to introduce a root type as follows:

```
[XmlRoot("ArrayOfSounds")]
public class CSoundsRoot
{
    public CSoundsRoot() { this.Sounds = new List<CSound>(); }

    [XmlElement("CSound")]
    public List<CSound> Sounds { get; set; }
}
```

Then do:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CSoundsRoot))
var root = (CSoundsRoot)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
var sounds = root == null ? new List<CSounds>() : root.Sounds;
```

As an aside, bugs in XML deserialization can often be diagosed by *serializing* your type and comparing the observed XML with the expected XML.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WQIvZQ).